# Regex hangs in Oracle 11g

Tags: regex, oracle

I am using Oracle 11g. The following statement takes around 3 seconds to execute:

```
select  case when regexp_like(
    'blahblahblahblah.blah@blah-blah.blah.gov.uk', 
    '^[\-a-zA-Z0-9_''^&\+\?\:]+(\.?[\-a-zA-Z0-9_''^&\+\?\:]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$') 
    then 'true' else 'false' end
```

Adding another character to the email address:

```
'blahblahblahblah.blahx@blah-blah.blah.gov.uk'
```

takes 6 seconds. Another character 12, then 24, 48, and so on. So:

```
'blahblahblahblah.blahxxxxx@blah-blah.blah.gov.uk'
```

takes around 96 seconds to run.

However, remove the hyphen:

```
'blahblahblahblah.blahxxxxx@blahblah.blah.gov.uk'
```

and it runs instantly.

Anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: Regardless of the performance problem, you seem to have two typos there: the first two character classes contain `A-z` instead of `A-Z`. This includes the six character `[\]^_\`` in the pattern (as their code points lie between the upper case and lower case letters). Additionally, there is no need for any of the escapes in the character classes.

Comment: There's a really good [article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) on matching email addresses; start there. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex is causing [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Briefly, your regex has terms that can *both* capture the same part of the input, but fails to do so. The regex engine must try all combinations before failing and due to the matching tree created, each extra character doubles the number of ways the match can be made. Creating and traversing this tree leads to a geometrically exponential execution time proportional to 2^n - which you are seeing.

You may find that changing your dual expression to a possessive quantifier (ie `++` rather than `+`) stops this behaviour, because with `++` once characters are consumed, they *stay* consumed.

---

Incidentally, this expression

```
[\-a-zA-z0-9_''^&\+\?\:]
```

may be rewritten as:

```
[-\w''^&+?:]
```

Because:

- inside a character class (almost) all characters lose their special regex meaning
- a dash first or last is a literakl dash (not a range)
- `\w` == `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: In particular, the part that is causing the catastrophic backtracking is `(\.?[\-a-zA-z0-9_''^&\+\?\:]+)*`.

Comment: Marked as correct, since it was due to catastrophic backtracking. +1 to @m.buettner for pointing out the part that was causing it. Changing (\.?[\-a-zA-z0-9_''^&\+\?\:]+)* to (\.[\-a-zA-z0-9_''^&\+\?\:]+)*   (in other words, removing the initial question mark) solved the issue. Cheers